# How to add to UINavigationBar title background and padding

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to implement this design into app.

[image: Needle view]

My first plan was to add solid background and some padding to title view, but I couldn't find any info. As I understood I can set only title view text attributes via setTitleTextAttributes on [UINavigationBar appearance]

Now my Navigation Bar looks like this 
[image]

**What is the better way to implement this design into app?**

Comment: My suggestion would be to subclass the the `UINavigationBar`, but there are other options. This [link](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/09/custom-uinavigationbars-techniques/) provides some good information on two ways to do that (but it's a bit old). This [link](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/) also has some good information on how to customize without subclassing. Apple also has some samplecode you could look through, but it's a little overwhelming: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:

1.set the checkers pattern as the background image.
2.create a UILabel with desired with and height, set text or attributed text.
3.`self.navigationItem.titleView = yourLabel`

This is more robust than simply making the whole thing a background image because it allows you to change the title for different screens while having the same checkered background.